# Add delay to microphone (using pulseaudio)

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

Does pulseaudio have an option to add a custom delay to a microphone input? Background is, that I use a greenscreen with my webcam and this introduces an 1.5second delay.

I found this post here: [How can I delay sound in the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625366/how-can-i-delay-sound-in-the-system) There a comment recommends using the advanced option in pavucontrol. For the mic I found this to have no effect.